# Rails 3 / Devise: Checking to see if users have any of multiple roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, roles

I have a users model with Devise, and I've set up roles so users can be assigned either one or multiple roles. If I want to check for a user's role in say, a view, the following code works...

```
<% if current_user.roles.include? Role.find_by_name('Administrator') %>
     You are an administrator!
<% end %>
```

But now, let's say I want to check if a user has one of multiple roles, to see if they're either an Administrator or Editor. I was certain the following would work....

```
<% if current_user.roles.include? Role.find_by_name('Administrator' || 'Editor') %>
```

...but it doesn't, it only works if you're an administrator and ignores checking all other roles after the first one in that list. I've tried other combinations like Role.find_by_name(['Administrator','Editor']) and whatnot, to no success. Exactly how would I format this to accomplish checking for multiple roles? I've hunted all over Google but all examples uses a single role.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem is that when you use the syntax 'Administrator' || 'Editor' it will not create an sql OR syntax. Instead what happens is that Ruby evaluates that 'Administrator' is considered a TRUE value and passes it on to the find_by_name method. Editor never gets send.

The second problem is that even if you change the syntax to ['Administrator', 'Editor'], the find_by_name method always returns only one record.

So I would probably do something like this:

```
Role.where(:name => ['Administrator', 'Editor']).all
```

That will return those two roles.

### Edit

I thought a litte further about this because it's not really a best practice solution to place this kind of database logic in the views. Here is another way that is a little more along the MVC concept:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def has_role?(*role_names)
    self.roles.where(:name => role_names).present?
  end
end

# In the views
<% if current_user.has_role?('Administrator', 'Editor') %>
```

Comment: That makes sense and is informative, thanks. However, the above didn't work right away (oddly returned true for any role), but with some tinkering I was able to make it work by modifying it as <% if current_user.roles.where(:name => ['Administrator','Editor']).present? %>

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out. I also thought of another way it could be done. I edited my answer to show it.

Comment: Cool. I know it's not good practice in the view, just trying to get something to work right now, refactor later. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Using an application helper here is the idea I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on cancan: http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan It will help you to keep authorization rules in one place, not spreading it through your views and controllers.

Comment: I already do have Cancan integrated and working in my app. However in this particular case, I need to define permissions on a single form field, not the entire model.

Answer (score 0):

With devise 3 and above use `current_user.has_any_role?(:Administrator, :Editor)`

Below are all the devise methods for checking role that can be used;

```
current_user.has_role?(role_name, resource = nil)
current_user.has_all_roles?(*args)
current_user.only_has_role?(role_name, resource = nil)
current_user.has_any_role?(*args)
```